# Sending outlook mail to multiple users with different email content using python

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I have tried to automate the outlook mail to multiple recipient with different content, but I keep getting this below error.

Error:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pritch\Desktop\email.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(df['Name'][i], df['Email_id'][i])
  File "C:\Users\Pritch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3804, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Pritch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3805, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client
import time


path = r'c:\Users\Abc\Desktop\content.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';', encoding='cp1252')
print(df)


for i in df.index:
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.Subject = 'Test Mail'
    #mail.HTMLBody = '<h3>This is HTML Body</h3>'
    print(df['Name'][i], df['Email_id'][i])
    mail.To = df['Email_id'][i]

    mail.HTMLBody = '''\
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
        <p>Hello ''' + df['Name'][i] + ''',<br>
        <p> Please refer your score.<br>
        <body> ''' + str(df['Content'][i]) + ''' </br></body>
        <font color ='blue'>
       <br>Thanks</>
        </font>
       <br></br>
       <font color ='red'>
        Kindly do not reply to this email.<t1>
       </font>
         </p>
        </body>
        </style>
        </html>
        '''

    mail.Send()
```

Comment: Why not just use `df.iterrows`?  When you printed the `df`, does it show the column names you expect, spelled exactly that way?

Answer (score 0):

The code for sending emails looks good. I don't see anything strange there.

The `To` property of the `MailItem` class accepts a semicolon-delimited string list of display names for the `To` recipients for the Outlook item. Make sure that the string is well formatted with a proper encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be done in Python? If your data is in a CSV, you probably have access to Excel, and if you do, you can run the code below, in Excel, to achieve your goals(s).

```
In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)
```

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm